# Saving a SVG polygon with matrix-applied vertices from Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, svg, transform

I loaded up a simple triangle in Inkscape which looked like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="100" height="100" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <polygon points="20 20 80 20 50 80" fill="#fff"/>
</svg>
```

after resizing it a bit, I get the following output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="100" height="100" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <polygon transform="matrix(1 0 0 .43775 0 28.595)" points="20 20 80 20 50 80" fill="#fff"/>
</svg>
```

Is it possible to save the SVG such that the points has the matrix transformation applied to it? For example, doing the transformation above by hand, it should have the following output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="100" height="100" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <polygon points="20 37.35 80 37.35 50 63.635" fill="#fff" />
</svg>
```

I tried playing around with the matrix options, operations here only appear to modify the transformation definition instead of being applied to the actual vertices:

[image: matrix options]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the preferences under 'Behavior → Transforms' make sure the 'Store transformation' option is set to 'Optimized' to make Inkscape manipulate coordinates directly, if possible, and less likely to add a `transform`-attribute.

If you want to apply an already added `transform`, sometimes grouping and ungrouping helps, but there is also the ['Apply Transforms' extension](https://github.com/Klowner/inkscape-applytransforms) available for this purpose.